# URL working in dev doesn't work on production server

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a stored proc that has url in its result set and onclick opens a new page with that url its working fine on my box but not on production server.

Here is my aspx:

```
 function NavigateOnClick(sender, eventArgs) {
     try {
         var row = eventArgs.get_item().get_row().get_index();
         var url = sender.get_rows().get_row(row).get_cell(0).get_text();

         window.open(url);
     }
     catch (e) {

     }
 }
```

The URL format is `../cellsiteEdit.aspx?cellsiteId=bhjhj`. It opens a new window with

```
/CellSiteEdit.aspx?CellSiteId=08C05834
```

but the URL should be

```
/LiveLease/CellSiteEdit.aspx?CellSiteId=08C05
```

and I am getting file or directory not found error. It works fine on my box.

Comment: That doesn't look like aspx code to me? It's JavaScript right? Could you open the page in Chrome or Firefox with firebug and console.log the url variable to see if it is what you think it is? Not working is one of the worst descriptions you could give to your problem. The only valid answer to that is "you did something wrong". Is the window opening? Did you get a JavaScript error?

Comment: Could you please let me know is your url is like: http://www.domainname.com/cellsiteEdit.aspx?cellsiteId=bhjhj ? or like http://www.domainname.com/.../cellsiteEdit.aspx?cellsiteId=bhjhj

Comment: it is supposed to be LiveLease/CellSite.aspx?id=88A296CB-E5BB instean it is like /cellsite.aspx?id=

Comment: When you say "it works find on my box," does it have the "LiveLease" in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
window.open(Regex.Replace(url, "../", ""));
```